# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies and some weird error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to filter the array by multiple conditions. This is working but getting few errors.

Here is the App.js code

```js
import "./styles.css";
import keywords from "./keywords.json";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [finalData, setFinalData] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [range, setRange] = useState(50);

  const filterByCategory = (keywords) => {
    return keywords.filter((item) => item.type.includes(category));
  };

  const filterByRange = (keywords) => {
    return keywords.filter((item) => item.search <= range);
  };

  const funcRange = (event) => {
    setRange(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let result = keywords;
    result = filterByRange(result);
    result = filterByCategory(result);
    setFinalData(result);
  }, [category, range]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <input
        type="range"
        min={50}
        max={100}
        value={range}
        onChange={funcRange}
      />
      <select
        name="category"
        id="category"
        onChange={(event) => setCategory(event.target.value)}
      >
        {[...keywords].map((option) => (
          <option value={option.type} key={option.id}>
            {option.type}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p>{category}</p>
      <h3>{range}</h3>
      {finalData.map((item) => (
        <>
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.name} - {item.search} - {item.type}
          </li>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is keywords.json file

```json
[
  {
    "name": "google",
    "search": 50,
    "type": "search"
  },
  {
    "name": "google",
    "search": 80,
    "type": "image"
  },
  {
    "name": "google",
    "search": 50,
    "type": "maps"
  },
  {
    "name": "yahoo",
    "search": 60,
    "type": "search"
  },
  {
    "name": "youtube",
    "search": 75,
    "type": "search"
  },
  {
    "name": "youtube",
    "search": 65,
    "type": "video"
  }
]
```

Everything is working perfectly but I'm getting this error in console.

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'filterByCategory' and 'filterByRange'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

If I add 'filterByCategory' and 'filterByRange' to the useEffect dependency, I'm getting the below error.

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

Here is the [CodeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-bird-fmwg4b?file=/src/App.js)

Also, for weird reason. Wrong category item is showing on Initial load and I see duplicate items in the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion occurs because you haven't memoized the inner functions with `useCallback`; their identity changes on each render, and the effect fires, etc. (Strictly speaking, they wouldn't need to be inner functions at all, but free functions that accept `keywords` and the facet to filter upon, in which case they wouldn't need to be dependencies.)

However, you shouldn't do that here – instead of using an effect and state to compute the filtered data, do it with `useMemo`, since it's strictly derivable from your current state.

```
export default function App() {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
  const [range, setRange] = useState(50);

  const funcRange = (event) => {
    setRange(event.target.value);
  };
  
  const finalData = React.useMemo(() => {
    return keywords
      .filter((item) => item.search <= range)
      .filter((item) => item.type.includes(category));
  }, [keywords, category, range]);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most people will advice to using `useMemo`, for something like this.

Personally I think in most cases it's not required.  The reason why the Lint errors is there is because the function will be created every render, and that's why the advice for `useMemo`.

But there is a much easier way to prevent a function been re-created on each render, just don't put it inside the function.

There are a couple of nice advantages here too, if you think about how React handles hooks, it works like a bit of a stack, it's the reason why Hooks have to be kept in the same order.  So as well as avoiding the performance hit of using a `useMemo`, you get the advantage of not worrying about Hook ordering, and that can be handy for function early termination that would normally break the hooks.

So in your example you only need to change a few things..

First move the two function outside of the App function->

```
const filterByCategory = (keywords, category) => {
  return keywords.filter((item) => item.type.includes(category));
};

const filterByRange = (keywords, range) => {
  return keywords.filter((item) => item.search <= range);
};

export default function App() {.......
```

You will notice you have to add the extra parameters, but that in itself is not a bad thing either, as you have now made the code more re-usable.

Of course next you just have to add those parameters at the calling end.

```
result = filterByRange(result, range);
result = filterByCategory(result, category);
```

Updated Sandbox -> [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-swartz-hvenkz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I avoid duplication in the dropdown? Also, during the Initial load. I see an item which belongs to different category. How can I avoid that? (Like the above screenshot)

Comment: You can use a Set to make the list unique, I've updated the Sandbox with this in..  Oh, and don't forget to use keys when iterating arrays.  To avoid the strange initial render values, seen as search is the default for the dropdown just make sure your `useState` sets this as the default..

Comment: @AvaJuan  Updated Sandbox with fixes..

Comment: While this approach works, there's no need to use extra state for the filtered data. Also, using state like this will cause an extraneous render; if you add `console.log(finalData);` you will see the component update with no `finalData`, followed by the filtered data. Using `useMemo` to derive the filtered state will not cause that.

Comment: @AKX  Yes, the state might not be required, but if finalData was from an effect it would be very handy.  But if the extra render was really a big issue, then there is `useRef`.  Still stand by my answer for the advantages it has over `useMemo`.   And especially as it requires less for the OP to change.  Remember this is NOT code review.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean with "if finalData was from an effect". The only place where the `finalData` state atom is set is this effect. I don't know what advantages you're referring to. While this is not code review, the idiomatic React hooks way to derive new data from state/props _is_ `useMemo`.

Comment: @AKX  I mean if finalData was from say an async request, you would need state anyway for the store.   Have you an issue of people doing things differently to you?

Comment: But it's _not_ from an async request, in this case! And even if `keywords`, the source data here, was a state atom fetched in an effect in the component, I'd still filter it with `useMemo` and not use an additional state atom for the filtered state. I don't have an issue with people doing things differently, but I do have a small issue with an UI that flashes an empty list of items before populating it correctly. :-)

Comment: @AKX  `but I do have a small issue with an UI that flashes an empty list of items before populating it correctly. :-)`  It's not a code review, and I think you know full well the flash could be avoided doing it this way too.   So I think your deliberately trying a put down..  So I will say, best leave it, seen as you don't understand what I'm saying..